# How combine the two same queries (fetch and fetchall)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fetch

I have two queries (exactly the same), which I would like to merge

**The first query:**

```
$stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date_parcel,"%d/%m/%Y") AS formatted_date from validated WHERE name = :name group by age order by age DESC');
$stmt ->execute(array(
  ':name' => $_GET['name']
  ));
$orders = $stmt ->fetchall();
```

**It allows me to do my foreach** loop to put all the data in an HTML table

**The second query :**

```
$infos = $bdd->prepare('SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date_parcel,"%d/%m/%Y") AS formatted_date from validated WHERE name = :name group by age order by age DESC');
$infos ->execute(array(
  ':name' => $_GET['name']
  ));
$info = $infos ->fetch();
```

This is exactly **the same as before, but it allows me to use the data before my foreach loop** to display information.

The code looks like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <center><h3><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($info['data5'])). ' - ' . $info['data6']; ?></h3></center>
        ....
    </div>
</div>

....

<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($orders as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1"><?php echo $row['data1'] ?></td>
        <td colspan="1"><?php echo $row['data2'] ?></td>
        <td colspan="1"><?php echo $row['data3'] ?></td>
        <td colspan="1"><?php echo $row['data4'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

So I would like to be able to use a single request, how can I do it?
Thank you

Comment: Those GROUP BY's are invalid, will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return an unpredictable result on older versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use like this

```
$stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date_parcel,"%d/%m/%Y") AS formatted_date from validated WHERE name = :name group by age order by age DESC');
$stmt ->execute(array(
  ':name' => $_GET['name']
));
$orders = $stmt ->fetchall();
$info = $stmt ->fetch();
```

Maybe it works... Not Sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not possible, with your code, it can not know what $infos

Comment: Don't work, when I use var_dump, I have this result : 'boolean false'

Answer (score 1):

`fetchAll` returns an array so you can easily use it to get a specific row:

```
$stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date_parcel,"%d/%m/%Y") AS formatted_date from validated WHERE name = :name group by age order by age DESC');
$stmt ->execute(array(
  ':name' => $_GET['name']
  ));
$orders = $stmt ->fetchall();
$info = $orders[0];
```

Comment: Yeah ! Thank you, it works ! It's the best way to combine this two queries ?

Comment: Using `$orders[0]` directly or copying it by reference to `$info` might be a little more memory efficient, but I think that's negligible in this case.